# React configure variables based on environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my react app, I have a component say chart in which an external API is called.

While running in the local, the API URL will be `localhost:8080`
When deployed and the API URL should be `prod:8080`

The examples based on .env uses process.env and inside the component where the API is called process is undefined.

Is there a way to access the env file inside the component which runs on the browser.

Comment: If you're using CRA to set up your project, you may opt for its [embedded tooling](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) if you're using some custom set up based on your own Webpack configuration you may check out  [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), [crossenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) or simply make use of Webpack's [Define Plug-in](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Comment: The only thing you should bear in mind is that all of above solutions imply that your `process.env.SOMETHING` will be substituted with **the actual value** of corresponding environment variable on the build time (hence accessible client side) and you have to be cautious not to expose any sensitive data within your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRA:

React's [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) on environment variables:

"Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if they were declared locally in your JS files. By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_.`"

Otherwise you might use something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and import it in your application `index.tsx`

For your specific use case, you also want to have 2 `.env` files since you want one for `development` and `production`. So take a look a [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used).